# Using TPL to run Tasks in parallel

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, state-machine

I have a simple (just a test) state machine that accepts the following input strings `abc` and `ac`.  The state machine is set up as follows:

`s1  --> 'a' -->  s2`
`s2  --> 'b' -->  s3`
`s3  --> 'c' -->  s4`
`s2  -->          s4 (Epsilon transition)`

s1 is the start state
s4 is the accept state

I want to use TPL to execute `s1->s2->s3->s4` and `s1->s2->s3->s4` in parallel (independent of each other).

If I pass in 'abc' as the input the machine accepts, i.e.

`> Thread 1 - Consumed: a, from State: 1 to State: 2`
`> Thread 2 - Consumed: b, from State: 2 to State: 3`
`> Thread 3 - Epsilon transition from State: 2 to State: 3`
`> Thread 4 - Consumed: c, from State: 3 to State: 4`
`> Thread 4 - Accepted in state 4`

`Time taken = 19`

`Input 'abc' is valid`
`Press any key to exit`

But, if I pass in 'ac' I get this:

`> Thread 1 - Consumed: a, from State: 1 to State: 2`
`> Thread 2 - Epsilon transition from State: 2 to State: 3`
`> Thread 3 - Consumed: c, from State: 3 to State: 4`
`> Thread 3 - Accepted in state 4`
`> Thread 4 - Consumed: c, from State: 3 to State: 4`
`> Thread 4 - Accepted in state 4`

`Time taken = 39`

`Input 'ac' is not valid (Reason: RejectedAmbiguous)`
`Press any key to exit`

For some reason the state machine is accepting the same input twice (accepting in state 4), which shouldn't be possible because both lines of parallel execution accept different inputs.

I won't post all of the code as there is too much of it, but I will post the main bits so you get an idea of what I am doing wrong.

```
public enum eResult
{
    Accepted = 0,
    RejectedAmbiguous,
    RejectedNoResults,
    RejectedNoInitialState
}

public eResult Execute()
{
    var startState = States.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Initial);
    if (startState == null) return eResult.RejectedNoInitialState;

    tasks.Clear();

    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    Task t = new Task(() =>
        {
            foreach(Transition tr in getTransitions(startState))
            {
                var tr = trans[n];
                var actor = new Actor(tr.FromState, this.input);
                Task<Actor> task = Task<Actor>.Factory.StartNew(obj =>
                    {
                        return doTransitionFunction(tr, cts).Invoke((Actor)obj);
                    }, actor, cts.Token);
                buildContinuationTask(Transitions[tr], task, cts);
                tasks.Add(task);
            }
        }, cts.Token);

    t.RunSynchronously();

    try
    {
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    }
    catch (AggregateException ae)
    {
        foreach (Exception e in ae.Flatten().InnerExceptions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }

    eResult result = eResult.Accepted;

    if (!results.Any()) result = eResult.RejectedNoResults;
    else if (results.Where(r => r.State.Accepted).Count() > 1) result = eResult.RejectedAmbiguous;

    return result;
}

IEnumerable<Transition> getTransitions(AtomicState state)
{
    return Transitions.Keys.Where(k => k.FromState == state);
}

bool isAccept(Actor parcel)
{
    return (parcel.State.Accepted && parcel.Cursor.EOF());
}

Func<object, Actor> doTransitionFunction(Transition transition, CancellationTokenSource cts)
{
    return new Func<object, Actor>(obj =>
    {
        var ts = (Actor)obj;
        var cur = ts.Cursor.Peek();
        if (transition.Epsilon || transition.Input.Invoke() == cur)
        {
            if (!transition.Epsilon) ts.Cursor.MoveNext();
            ts.State = Transitions[transition];
            OnTransitioned(this, new TransitionedEventArgs(transition.FromState, ts.State, cur, transition.Epsilon, Task.CurrentId));
            if (isAccept(ts))
            {
                OnAccepted(this, new AcceptedEventArgs(ts.State, Task.CurrentId));
                results.Add(ts);
                cts.Cancel();
            }
        }
        return ts;
    });
}

void buildContinuationTask(AtomicState s, Task<Actor> antecedentTask, CancellationTokenSource cts)
{
    var trans = getTransitions(s).ToArray();
    for (int n = 0; n < trans.Count(); n++)
    {
        Transition tr = trans[n];
        Task<Actor> continuation = antecedentTask.ContinueWith<Actor>(antecdent =>
            {
                if (!cts.IsCancellationRequested)
                    return doTransitionFunction(tr, cts).Invoke((Actor)antecdent.Result.Clone());
                else
                    return (Actor)antecdent.Result.Clone();
            }, cts.Token, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, TaskScheduler.Current);
        buildContinuationTask(Transitions[tr], continuation, cts);
        tasks.Add(continuation);
    }
}
```

Correct me if this isn't possible, but what I want to happen is this:

For the 1st Parallel Task to accept `abc` as input:

s1 is a `Task<Actor>`
s2 is a continuation of s1
s3 is a continuation of s2
s4 is a continuation of s3

For the 2nd Parallel Task to accept `ac`:

s1 is a `Task<Actor>`
s2 is a continuation of s1
s3 is a continuation of s2 (this one is the epsilon move)
s4 is a continuation of s3

Both of these tasks have their own copy of the `Actor` object that will be passed from the main antecedent task into the continuation tasks.

I know I am almost there and I just need to solve this last mystery.

Comment: Just curious, why aren't you using TPL DataFlow?  It would simplify *much* of this.

Comment: I have never heard of TPL DataFlow.  Thank's for bringing this to my attention.  I will have a read up of it and see if it'll help me solve my problem. +1 for that.

Comment: Would you be open to a TPL DataFlow solution which does what you want, or do you want to stick strictly to the `Task`-based solution you have now?

Comment: I would accept either.  If I can make it work using a `Task` based solution I'd take that, but if I could do the same using TPL DataFlow that would also be great.  It would make it simple for me to see how it'll work using two different methods.

Comment: I have just been reading up on TPL DataFlow and while it appears very powerful I am not sure how it is able to keep track of the multiple Actor state objects when encountering states with multiple transitions?

Comment: I didn't have the time to look yesterday, but after I handle my mod and work duties, I'll see if I can get you an answer today (using both, preferably).

Comment: @casperOne thanks I'd appreciate that.  I am just having a go myself with a TPL DataFlow version and it's not as easy as I thought!

Answer (score 0):

After reading up about TPL DataFlow this is my attempt and it seems to work the way I want.

```
public interface IScrollableCursor
{
    void MoveNext();
    void MovePrevious();
    void MoveFirst();
    void MoveLast();
    bool BOF();
    bool EOF();
    char Peek();
    int CurrentPosition { get; }
}

[Serializable]
public abstract class AtomicState
{
    protected int stateId;
    protected bool accepted;

    public int StateId
    {
        get
        {
            return stateId;
        }
    }

    public AtomicState( int stateId )
    {
        this.stateId = stateId;
        this.accepted = false;
    }

    public AtomicState( int stateId, bool accepted )
        : this( stateId )
    {
        this.accepted = accepted;
    }

    public abstract bool Initial { get; }

    public bool Accepted
    {
        get
        {
            return accepted;
        }
    }

}


[Serializable]
public struct Actor : ICloneable
{
    private AtomicState state;
    private IScrollableCursor cursor;

    public AtomicState State
    {
        get
        {
            return state;
        }
        set
        {
            state = value;
        }
    }

    public IScrollableCursor Cursor
    {
        get
        {
            return cursor;
        }
    }

    public Actor( AtomicState state, IScrollableCursor cursor )
    {
        this.state = state;
        this.cursor = cursor;
    }

    public object Clone()
    {
        return this.DeepClone();
    }


}

public class Transition
{
    protected AtomicState fromState;
    protected Func<Char> input;
    protected bool epsilon;

    public AtomicState FromState
    {
        get
        {
            return fromState;
        }
    }

    public Func<Char> Input
    {
        get
        {
            return input;
        }
    }

    public bool Epsilon
    {
        get
        {
            return epsilon;
        }
    }

    public Transition( AtomicState fromState, Func<Char> input )
    {
        this.fromState = fromState;
        this.input = input;
    }

    public Transition( AtomicState fromState, bool epsilon )
        : this( fromState, null )
    {
        this.epsilon = epsilon;
    }


}

public class EpsilonTransition : Transition
{
    public EpsilonTransition( AtomicState fromState )
        : base( fromState, true )
    {
    }
}



public eResult Execute()
{
    var startState = States.FirstOrDefault( s => s.Initial );
    if ( startState == null ) return eResult.RejectedNoInitialState;

    tasks.Clear();

    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions options = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions();
    options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4;
    options.CancellationToken = cts.Token;

    // transitions an actor onto it's next state
    TransformBlock<Tuple<Transition, Actor>, Actor> actorTransitioner = new TransformBlock<Tuple<Transition, Actor>, Actor>( tr =>
        {
            return doTransitionFunction( tr.Item1, cts ).Invoke( tr.Item2 );

        }, options );

    BroadcastBlock<Actor> actorTransitionerBroadcaster = new BroadcastBlock<Actor>( a => { return a; } );

    ActionBlock<Actor> actorProcessor = new ActionBlock<Actor>( a =>
        {
            foreach ( Transition t in getTransitions( a.State ) )
            {
                actorTransitioner.Post( new Tuple<Transition, Actor>( t, (Actor)a.Clone() ) );
            }
        } );

    // link blocks
    actorTransitioner.LinkTo( actorTransitionerBroadcaster );
    actorTransitionerBroadcaster.LinkTo( actorProcessor );

    actorTransitionerBroadcaster.Post( new Actor( startState, input ) );

    try
    {
        actorTransitioner.Completion.Wait();
    }
    catch ( AggregateException ex )
    {
        foreach ( Exception ae in ex.Flatten().InnerExceptions )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( ae.Message );
        }
    }

    eResult result = eResult.Accepted;

    if ( !results.Any() ) result = eResult.RejectedNoResults;
    else if ( results.Where( r => r.State.Accepted ).Count() > 1 ) result = eResult.RejectedAmbiguous;

    return result;
}
```

I have added the constructs used in my attempt so it's easier to be reproduced.  It necessary I will post the entire code (about 12 classes).

Comment: Can you add more about what blocks mapped up with your original constructs?  That would help tremendously.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the constructs used by the block mapping.

Comment: Interestingly my solution seems to hang once it finds accepting routes.  I am not quite sure how to get the blocks to signal completion so I can return the results back to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to answer my own question after coming up with a much simpler solution.  I deduced that TPL DataFlow is not suitable for this as it would create circular data networks with no way of determining whether the computation has been completed, or not.  So I decided to bin it completely and go back to the drawing board.

I eventually discovered Paralell.ForEach() that does exactly what I wanted, run each transition in parallel by utilizing all processor cores:

```
public eResult Execute()
{
    var startState = States.FirstOrDefault( s => s.Initial );
    if ( startState == null ) return eResult.RejectedNoInitialState;

    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken token = cts.Token;

    Task t = new Task( () =>
        {
            Parallel.ForEach( getTransitions( startState ), new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 }, tr =>
            {
                var a0 = new Actor( tr.FromState, (IScrollableCursor)this.input.DeepClone() );
                var a1 = doTransitionFunction( tr, cts ).Invoke( a0 );
                if ( a0.State != a1.State )
                    processRecursively( a1.State, a0, cts );

            } );

        }, cts.Token );

    t.RunSynchronously();


    eResult result = eResult.Accepted;

    if ( !results.Any() ) result = eResult.RejectedNoResults;
    else if ( results.Where( r => r.State.Accepted ).Count() > 1 ) result = eResult.RejectedAmbiguous;

    return result;


}


void processRecursively( AtomicState s, Actor a0, CancellationTokenSource cts )
{
    Parallel.ForEach( getTransitions( s ), tr =>
        {
            var a1 = doTransitionFunction( tr, cts ).Invoke( a0 );
            if ( a0.State != a1.State )
                processRecursively( a1.State, a1, cts );
        } );
}
```